# Why the space of Fourier-Stieltjes transforms on a compact groups is same as the space of FT on compact groups?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $G$ be a locally compact group and we put
$L^{1}(G)= \ \text {The space of all complex functions which are integrable with respect to the Haar measure of } \ G.$

Let $\Gamma$ is  the dual group (or character group) of the locally compact abelian group $G$
(with addition as group operation), and we define the map(Fourier transform) from $L^{1}(G)$ to $C(\Gamma)$ as 
$$Fg(y)= \hat{g}(y):=\int_{G} <-x, y> g(x) dx; (y\in \Gamma),$$ 
where the symbol $<x, y>$ denotes the value of the character $y$ at the point $x$.

We consider, the algebras of all Fourier
transforms,
$A(\Gamma)  = \{ f:\Gamma \to \mathbb C : \exists  g  \in L^{1}(G) \ \text {such that} \ f(y)= \hat{g}(y)\}$

and the algebra of all Fourier-Stieltjes transforms on $\Gamma$,$B(\Gamma) = \{f:\Gamma \to \mathbb C : \exists \ \text {a bounded complex Borel measure } \ \mu  \ \text{on} \ G \  \text {such that} \ f(y) = \hat {\mu(y)}
  \}.$
 ($f(y)= \hat {\mu}(y)= \int_{G} <-x, y> d\mu(x); (y\in \Gamma )$)

**My questions are**: 
(1) In what sense we can think of $B(\Gamma)$ as a generalization of $A(\Gamma)$ ?

(2) If $\Gamma$ is compact; why, $A(\Gamma) = B(\Gamma)$ ?

---

Thanks,

Comment: If $\Gamma$ is compact, then $G$ is discrete. Then every (bounded) complex Borel measure is given by an $f \in L^1(G) \cong \ell^1(G)$.

Comment: Given $g\in L^1(G)$ and a Borel (or Lebesgue-Haar) measurable set $A$ define  $\mu_g(A)=\int_Ag(x)dx$, then $\mu$ is a bounded Borel (or Lebesgue-Haar) measure on $G$. That is $A(\Gamma)$ is contained in $B(\Gamma)$.